# How do you add a textfield to your Safari 5 Extension bar?

Tags: safari

The [Amazon Search Bar extension](http://echodot.com/creations/amazon_search_bar/) adds an Amazon search field to your extension bar, which is exactly what I'd like to do. I can't find an example on SO or Google and I don't think any of Apple's example use a text field like that. Any examples or suggestions about how to go about it would be very helpful.

I'm just getting started with Safari Extensions, so forgive me if there is an obvious answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari Extension Bar is just a piece of html, so you can easily put

```
<input type="text />
```

in it and style as you need.

If you want examples, you can just extract any safariextz with this command:

```
xar -xf SomeExt.safariextz
```

and look at the source files.

Comment: I also just realized you can also use the WebKit Inspector directly on an extension bar, just right click and select Inspect Element. Very helpful.